# REPLICACION SQL SERVER DESDE JAVA

Tags: java, sql, usercontrol

Disculpen mi poco conocimiento pero existe la replicacion sql server desde java, mi app crea usuarios de solo vista, pero para la replicacion debo meterme desde sql server y hacer todo eso, hay la manera o existe un metodo para hacerlo desde java.

Comment: La replicación suele ser un tema que se configura, administra y supervisa desde herramientas propias del motor. Nada impide, si el motor lo permite, hacer programas, en java o el lenguaje de tu elección, que tiren de los recursos que dicho motor provea para ayudar con esta tarea. Pero es un tema, generalmente, bastante amplio y que depende totalmente del motor que utilices, ya que no es parte del estándar, que solo define el lenguaje DML/DDL, que nada tiene que ver con replicación. Si no mencionas con qué motor trabajas, esto es imposible de responder.

Comment: Por otro lado, en los motores que yo conozco, la respuesta a esto suele abarcar libros enteros, por lo que resulta demasiado amplia para el formato del sitio.